# Auto reloading Django server on Docker

Tags: python, django, docker

I am learning to use Docker and I have been having a problem since yesterday (before I resorted to asking, I started to investigate but I could not solve the problem), my problem is that I have a Django project in my local machine, I also have the same project with Docker, but when I change my local project, it is not reflected in the container that the project is running. I would be very grateful if you could help me with this please. Thank you.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code

RUN apk update \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk add postgresql-dev \
    && pip install psycopg2 \
    && apk del build-deps

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pipenv

COPY ./Pipfile /code
RUN pipenv install --skip-lock --system --dev

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /code

COPY . /code

ENTRYPOINT [ "/code/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
# version de docker-compose con la que trabajaremos
version: '3'

# definiendo los servicios que correran en nuestro contenedor
services:
  web:
    restart: always
    build: .
    command: gunicorn app.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 #python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - static_volume:/code/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/code/mediafiles
    expose:
      - 8000
    environment:
      - SQL_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
      - SQL_DATABASE=postgres
      - SQL_USER=postgres
      - SQL_PASSWORD=postgres
      - SQL_HOST=db
      - SQL_PORT=5432
      - DATABASE=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file: .env
  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:10.5-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/code/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/code/mediafiles
    ports:
      - 1337:80
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

And a little doubt here, is it a good practice to store the environment variables in Dockerfile or docker-compose ?, I use .env but I have seen in many places that they store the variables in docker-compose, as shown in the code of above

I hope you can help me, any recommendation about my project, is very well received, as I comment, I'm new to Docker but I really like it a lot and I would like to learn more about it.

Comment: Unlike `runserver` gunicorn will not automatically restart its workers when the code changes, unless the argument `--reload` is used. This is not recommended for production.

Comment: So, do you recommend removing gunicorn and nginx? and only leave the native django server for development?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How people usually approach this is to have a separate `docker-compose` configurations for development and production environment, e.g. `local.yml` and `production.yml`. That way you can use `runserver` while developing (which you'll probably find more suitable since you'll get a lot of debug information) and `gunicorn` on production.

I'd recommend looking into https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django project which has a lot of Django good practices integrated as well as a good out of the box Docker configuration. You can create a test project using the `cookiecutter` and then inspect how they do the Docker setup, including environment variables.

Comment: It works fine but now I have a small problem, when installing a package "djangorestframework" I give it "pipenv install djangorestframework" but when I want to import it from "settings.py" it says "no module named rest_framework". I guess I'll have to do "build" again for that? Is there a way to synchronize everything without having to build again and again?

Comment: Yes, that's kind of the idea - you have to (re)build the container for it to reflect changes. AFAIK there is no (good) way to overcome this and you probably shouldn't in respect to the ideas of what Docker containers are for.